# Android app launches to white screen on device

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android dev, and I've been going through similar topics but no help yet.
I created an app and it was running before I added functionality to scan a QR code. It works on the emulator but when I run it on my Samsung device it launches to a white screen and this is what my log says:

```
Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of .....
$ adb shell am force-stop com.KtvrBusSerice.KtvrBusService.KtvrBusService
$ adb shell am start -n "com.KtvrBusSerice.KtvrBusService.KtvrBusService/com.KtvrBusSerice.KtvrBusService.KtvrBusService.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 22097 on device samsung-sm_g930f-0123456789ABCDEF
D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x79
Application terminated.
```

Comment: which android studio version you are using?

Comment: Try `Run>Attach debugger to android process`

Comment: Aditya Vyas-Lakkan version 2.2.3

Comment: @Egek92 I tried but the OK button is grayed out

Answer (score 0):

it is due to cold start issue. refer https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html
it may occur  if you perform heavy initialization at launch time.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to AndroidManifest.xml within your

```
<application>
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
</application>
```

Comment: I added that code to my manifest but i'm now getting this in my log "03:02:43 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 03:03:31 PM Gradle build finished in 47s 288ms 03:06:44 PM Session 'app': Error Launching activity"

Comment: There must be some other error also. Can you please paste the same?

Comment: Try to uninstall the app and then re-install the app again